# Wordpress taxonomy template

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called productcategory that is declared like this

```
register_taxonomy(
    'productcategory',
    'product',
    array(  'hierarchical' => FALSE, 'label' => __('Kategorier'),  
                    'public' => TRUE, 'show_ui' => TRUE,
                    'query_var' => 'productcategory',
                    'rewrite' => true )
);
```

When i browse to http://www.myserver.com/productcategory/mycategory i want to see a list of all products in that category. To do that i created the template "taxonomy-productcategory.php" in my theme folder. However, when i browse to that URL it uses the index.php-page, AND no posts (products) are shown. I have Googled and read on Codex but i can't understand this. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in WP (3.4.1), i changed the permalink format back to default and then back to my prefered and then it worked again!